# how can we create a quote without an Opportunity

Tags: quote

I am trying to create a custom button for New quote in 'Quote' record page. I dont wan't Opportunity field.But that field is required in 'Quote'. Any solution?

Comment: By default, `Quote` has master-detail relationship with `Opportunity`. So, a quote cannot exist without a parent opportunity. Can you elaborate on your question?

Comment: also, quote's currency comes from opportunity's currency

Answer (score 2):

Try installing the unmanaged package by Salesforce Labs called [Simple Quote/Invoice/Order](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000001TLtcEAG). You can utilize it to create custom quotes (doesn't use the Quote object) by creating a PDF you can send to your customer. It's available on the App Exchange or from their [repository on GitHub](https://github.com/salesforcelabs?page=1) if you want to customize it.

Answer (score 0):

Since the Summer '23 release of Salesforce one can enable "Create Quotes Without a Related Opportunity" in Setup / Quote Settings.

See Salesforce release notes for more information: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_sales_quotes_without_opportunities.htm&release=244&type=5