# Is there a way to create/add NEW Quote/Invoice in Order sObject?

Tags: object, quote

Is there a way to create/add a NEW Quote/Invoice directly in the Order Object? I have noticed that only the Opportunity Object have this option (to add/create a NEW Quote). SO, I was wondering if there's a way to do this at the Order Object as well?

Answer (score 0):

Opportunity is a mandatory field to be populated during quote creation process.

If you try to create the Quote from any custom way, somehow you have to pass the opportunity Id otherwise it will not let you create it.

Note :- By default, Quote has master-detail relationship with Opportunity. So, a quote cannot exist without a parent opportunity.

Try installing the unmanaged package by Salesforce Labs called  [Simple Quote/Invoice/Order](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000001TLtcEAG). You can utilize it to create custom quotes (doesn't use the Quote object) by creating a PDF you can send to your customer. It's available on the App Exchange or from their [repository on GitHub](https://github.com/salesforcelabs?page=1) if you want to customize it.

Reference link :- [Link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/324470/how-can-we-create-a-quote-without-an-opportunity#:%7E:text=By%20default%2C%20Quote%20has%20master,exist%20without%20a%20parent%20opportunity.)

Comment: If you think [an answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/324476/62544) provided to other question is appropriate here too, you should flag this question as duplicate instead of copy-pasting the answer.